# JSON unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string

```
    {"rules": {
  "firstName": {
    "required": true,
    "range": "[2,50]"
  },
  "lastName": {
    "required": true,
    "range": "[2,50]"
  },
  "email": {
    "required": true,
    "email": true
  },
  "email2": {
    "equalTo": "email",
    "required": true
  },
  "password": {
    "required": true,
    "range": "[5,25]"
  },
  "password2": {
    "equalTo": "password",
    "required": true
  },
  "termsConfidentiality": {
    "required": true
  }
},
"messages": {

    "termsConfidentiality": {
        "required": "You must accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy in order to register."
    },
    "termsConfidentiality": {
        "required": "You must accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy in order to register."
    }
},
"errorPlacement": function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr('name') == 'termsConfidentiality') {
                        error.appendTo($('#terms'));
    }
}
}
```

which i am keeping in a variable called `rules`. When i do `JSON.parse(rules)` i get the following error

```
39 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON
```

Everything worked fine until i added the `errorPlacement`. The unexpected token is the letter `'u'` in the word `'function'`. What is the proper way to format it so i can parse it afterwards?

Comment: A function is not valid in JSON.

Comment: but when you use JQuery Validator you need to use the work "function" when using errorPlacement. If i enter the validators normally without placing them in a variable and parsing it afterwards, it works fine. So there must be a way to format the function properly using this method.

Comment: Well they are not using JSON if it has a function in it.

Comment: http://www.json.org/ Checkout this site to know more about the data types allowed in JSON.

Comment: @BojanS. There's not. You don't need to do `JSON.parse` though. Just do `rules.errorPlacement` and whatnot directly.

Comment: This site is really handy for validating JSON strings [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) I've found

Comment: You also have two keys of the same name in your "messages" object, which is invalid as well. What are you trying to do with this code? Note that JSON is a string format without the enclosing quote marks, this is just an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @epascarello said, "A function is not valid in JSON". Don't mix up JSON and Javascript, they are independent of each other even if they share a name. You can't have functions in JSON because it is not a language, it is a data format. You may be able to encapsulate the function as a string then run it with the `eval` function, although I wouldn't recommend that, that's a pretty dirty hack, and quite unsafe.

Comment: ok thanks, i will look for another solution that doesn't involve using JSON this way

Comment: like @ceejayoz said, i simply did rules.errorPlacement. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, dont mix up json and javascript.
Also in messages you have duplicate keys:

```
"messages": {

    "termsConfidentiality": {
        "required": "You must accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy in order to register."
    },
    "termsConfidentiality": {
        "required": "You must accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy in order to register."
    }
}
```

Valid JSON::

```
  {
        "rules": {
            "firstName": {
                "required": true,
                "range": "[2,50]"
            },
            "lastName": {
                "required": true,
                "range": "[2,50]"
            },
            "email": {
                "required": true,
                "email": true
            },
            "email2": {
                "equalTo": "email",
                "required": true
            },
            "password": {
                "required": true,
                "range": "[5,25]"
            },
            "password2": {
                "equalTo": "password",
                "required": true
            },
            "termsConfidentiality": {
                "required": true
            }
        },
        "messages": {
            "termsConfidentiality": {
                "required": "You must accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy in order to register."
            }
        }
    }
```